# 403 (Site Disabled) in SignalR hosted in Azure

Tags: azure, signalr

My App is hosted in Azure Websites and uses SignalR

Azure started a new thing where they shut down the website if it's been idle for more than a few seconds. i.e. no requests.

For some reason, having an active outgoing websockets connection does not seem to keep the website "active". So the WebSockets client starts getting 403 (Site Disabled) until you make another http request.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?
Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: Please rephrase your question. It's difficult to understand what you are saying.

Comment: This is not a new thing with windows azure, just something that is automatic and not changeable on free sites.  There is an "Always On" option under the configure tab for your Web App, but "This feature can only be enabled when in the Basic or Standard pricing tier."

Comment: It is new. It was working fine last week. and I am not using free sites. I am using shared and "Always On" is not an option there either. Always on wasn't even in the old portal because this is a NEW thing.

Comment: Shared tier gives you just 35 websocket connections, which are easily achievable with SignalR: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/websites/ you may want to upgrade to basic.

Comment: I am nowhere near the 35 connections and my clients don't have 600 a year